# Why is making a comparison in an oracle function slower than without it and how can I improve the performance?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, optimization

I have the following query:

```
select o.a1
from d
     inner join c on d.cid = c.cid
     inner join o on c.oid = o.oid
     inner join l on d.did = l.did
     inner join a on l.lid = a.lid
where (case when d.name = 'some name' and d.q > 0 and
            ((l.p in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
              and a.db != 0) or
             (d.m is null or d.m > some_value)) then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

This query runs around 200ms. Now I want to incapsulate the comparison logic in a function like this:

```
function is_that_true
(
  a nvarchar2,
  b number,
  c nvarchar2,
  d number,
  e date
)
return number result_cache
is
begin
    return (case when a = 'some name' and b > 0 and
                ((c in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
                  and d != 0) or
                 (e is null or e > some_value)) then 1 else 0 end);
end;
```

When I run the aforementioned query by replacing the comparison with a function call it runs much slower(around 1 minute). It's probably because Oracle does some optimizations in the background. Is it possible to use function calls and still get acceptable performance in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create function based index. The way you are calling function, optimizer is executing function for each row.
Cheers

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Hi Mathias, Can you please guide me why my comment is not answering the question?

Comment: I see now that this is really an answer to the question. Apologies! But having said that, it would help if you could elaborate a bit more, e.g. show how to "create a function based index".